# Android Screen Orientation

Tags: android

I developed an application in portrait mode in Android.
What changes do I have to do, that my application  will be also fit for landscape orientation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, you don't HAVE to make any changes for it to fit to landscape. It you're using the standard `wrap_content` and `fill_parent` for your width and height, your layout will automatically adjust when you change orientations.

With that said, you will often WANT to change to a different layout when switching from portrait to landscape, as a layout that looks good vertically may be unusable when horizontal. You can add a new folder beside your `/layout` folder titled `layout-land`. In this, make a new XML file with the same title as your previous layout, and then change the layout from there. Be sure that any and all defined `android:id`s exist in both the original and landscape layout.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `layout_width` as "fill_parent" where ever required.